# Image is not showing up in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image

Hello here is my code :

```
        import React, {useState}  from 'react';
    import './Soal2.css';
    import img3 from './pink3.jpg';
    import hamburger from './products/humburger.jpg';
    import kimchi from './products/kimchi.jpg';
    import topokki from './products/topokki.jpg'
    import sushi from './products/sushi.jpg';
    
    
    function Soal2() {
    
      const [listProducts, setListProducts] = useState([{
        menu: 'Batagor',
        gambar: `url(${humburger})`,
        harga: 10000
      },
      {
      menu: 'Kimchi',
      image: `url(${kimchi})`,
      harga: 15000
      },
      {
      menu: 'Topokki',
      gambar:`url(${topokki})`,
      harga: 20000
      },
      {
      menu: 'Sushi',
      gambar: `url(${sushi})`,
      harga: 25000
      } 
      ])
    
    
    
        return (
          <div className="Soal-2">
      <div className="jawaban-2">
      </div>
      {listProducts.map((product, index) => {
        const key = `product-${product.menu}-${index}`
            return <div key={key}>
              <img src={product.gambar} /> ---> this image is not showing up
              <h3>{product.menu}</h3>
              <p>{product.harga}</p>
            </div>
          })}
          </div>
</div>
</div>
        );
      }
      
export default Soal2;
```

the problem is image is not showing up. But the text h3 and p at the bottom img is already showing up. the error is img element must have an alt prop react...
but when i try to type alt="food menu" the image stil not showing up. Please help me... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the url from the object like:

```
{
menu: 'Batagor',
gambar: humburger,
harga: 10000
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In React native the img needs a width and height in the style prop like this:

```
<img src={product.gambar} style={{height: 100, width: 100}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove url from json like this

```
     {
      menu: 'Topokki',
      gambar:topokki,
      harga: 20000
      }
```

And use in image like this

```
<img src={listProducts[0].gambar} alt="{listProducts[0].menu" />
```